# BLE device re-connects after cancelPeripheralConnection (How to forget a BLE device?)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a BLE device that connects to an iOS device after it has been chosen through a fairly standard user interface (tap on the device entry shown in a UITableView).

The connection is simple enough- some internal processing followed by calling the CBCentralManager's connectPeripheral(peripheral: options:).

There is a requirement to 'forget' the device (so that the iPhone won't connect to it automatically again). I call the cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral:), however the device still connects back to the phone automatically.

**How can I stop the BLE device from automatically re-connecting after the cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral:) method is called?**

Comment: Is it a HID device?

Comment: No, not really. There's nothing on the device that could be used to forget the association on the peripheral. Does that answer the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to forget a device using code. You have to manually go to the settings and forget the device.

The system will automatically connect to a paired device when the bluetooth is turned on or if the device initiates a connection. Are you calling connect after the `cancelPeripheralConnection` call?

Comment: Sorry- yes, I was calling cancelPeripheralConnection. I've found that I have to put it in a `while (peripheral.state == .connecting)` loop to make sure the device doesn't connect next time!